# Java-like Iterator in Swift

Tags: swift, iterator

How to iterate array without using position (index) `i` and `for`/`for in` loop?

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]

for var i = 0; i < a.count; i++ {
    //
}

for item in a {
    //
}
```

Comment: What is your intention by doing this?

Comment: I need to hold iteration context between asynchronous operations. But the reason of posting this answer and question is simple - I came from Java (Android) world and I know the word "Iterator" but googling "Iterators in Swift" did not give me simple answer so I decided to share solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SequenceType` (which `CollectionType`, and thus all Swift collections including array, conform to) is pretty simple. It requires you provide a `generate()` function that returns a type conforming to `GeneratorType`.

`GeneratorType` in turn only needs to provide one method: a `next()` that returns each element until the elements are exhausted. It returns an optional, returning `nil` after the last element is returned. This makes them pretty similar to Java iterators, only with `next` and `hasNext` combined into one via use of optionals.

Swift’s `for…in` is really syntactic sugar for a combination of getting a generator and then repeatedly calling `next` on it:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
for i in a { print(i) }
// is equivalent to:
var g = a.generate()
// the generator, being stateful, must be declared with var
while let i = g.next() { print(i) }
```

If using generators like this, take note of the comment above the definition of `GeneratorType` in the std lib doc:

> Encapsulates iteration state and interface for iteration over a
>   *sequence*.
>
> - Note: While it is safe to copy a *generator*, advancing one
>     copy may invalidate the others.

Since writing a generator for a collection often involves a lot of boiler plate, there is a helper type, `IndexingGenerator`, that can be used.  This implements a generator that starts at `startIndex`, and returns the value at that index and increments the index each time. A `generate()` that returns an `IndexingGenerator` is provided as the default implementation for `CollectionType`, which means if this is good enough for your purposes, you don’t need to implement `generate` when implementing a collection:

```
struct Bitfield: CollectionType {
    let data: UInt
    var startIndex: UInt { return 0 }
    var endIndex: UInt { return UInt(sizeofValue(data)*8) }
    subscript(idx: UInt) -> Bit {
        return (data >> idx) & 1 == 0
        ? Bit.Zero : Bit.One
    }
    // no need to implement generate()
}
```

This default was added in Swift 2.0. Prior to that, you had to provide a minimal generator that just returned an `IndexingGenerator(self)`.

Comment: You always need to implement `generate`. `IndexingGenerator` gives us a simple implementation of generator that can be used with any collection that conforms to CollectionType but you still need to implement `generate` that returns `IndexingGenerator(self)`.

Comment: Not in 2.0. It is now defaulted. Have edited to clarify.

Comment: Ok, that is because of inheritance from `_CollectionGeneratorDefaultsType` protocol with default implementation of `generate()`.

Comment: Sarcasm detected :) I prefer things to be clear. Swift 2.0 is in beta and not everyone have time to read documentation in depth to find these things. Nice answer by the way. Thanks!

Comment: It’s a fair point that I should have tagged the feature as 2.0 though. But I do think people should be answering with 2.0 rather than 1.2 (with a 1.2 version below, for now) because these answers are for the long-term, 1.2 will be out of date in a couple of months.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `IndexingGenerator`:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]

var generator = a.generate()

while let item = generator.next() {
    //
}
```

**P. S.** I created and answered my own question because I did not find anything when tried to figure out how to use Java-like iterators in Swift.

Comment: You've found your own solution in 30 seconds (minus writing an answer = 5 seconds)? Why bother asking a question in the first place?

Comment: @akashivskyy To share solution with community. See my P. S.

Comment: I'm not sure what the rules are on this but I personally don't see a problem with it. Other people can still answer and provide better answers if they exist.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it's encouraged: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with the help of `IteratorProtocol`.

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
var aIterator = a.makeIterator()

while let aItem = aIterator.next() {
    // do something with array item
}
```

More on `IteratorProtocol` in Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/iteratorprotocol)

Answer (score -1):

if you use Java 8 you can use streams. 
As an example:

```
List<User> olderUsers = users.stream().filter(u -> u.age > 30).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks! But question is about Swift programming language.